# Xamarin.Android handling connection failures when calling web service

Tags: web-services, xamarin, soap, webmethod, system.net.webexception

We're developing warehouse app for picking items which sends requests to a web service on every item scan, e. g. to update the quantity scanned in DB. From the log files I saw thet every now and then the connection on android scanners is lost and that leads to item quantity not being updated or in worst case an app crash.

What would be the best way to handle such connection failures so that I can ensure that the call to web method was successul before continuing code execution? Should I define some variable which accepts response from the web method and repeat the call until success is returned? Or is there some smarter way?

Comment: Read up on Exponential Backoff with a retry pattern. You could also have a queue with the single purpose of managing that retry logic. Other than that this question is a bit broad.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for the suggestion! Maybe I'll use Polly to implement some retry logic with exponential backoff.